# Dropdown button remains open and does not close

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem as my dropdown menu stays open and doesn't close. Have I done something or do i need to add something?

Here is a screenshot to what i am referring too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX328.jpg

I have researched for a solution and I am unable to find anything relating to this issue

My code is:

````js
```
<div class="NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi">
                  <span class="NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7">
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#" onclick="showDropDown()" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3" data-ui-name="info"><span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon"><path d="M15.6 32s-.1 0 0 0h-.8c-2.7 0-5.6 0-8.4-.8-3-.9-4.6-2.4-4.7-4.7-.1-1.1.3-2.2 1-3.1 1.1-1.5 2.7-2.4 4.1-3.1.5-.3 1-.5 1.5-.8.6-.4 2-1.4 2.1-2.7 0-.6-.2-1.3-.8-2.1l-.6-.9c-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1.2-1.9-1.2-2.5-1-5.6.4-7.9.2-.3.4-.6.7-.9 1.8-2 4.3-3.1 7-3.1 2.7-.1 5.3 1.1 7.2 3 .3.3.6.7.8 1 1.4 2.3 1.5 5.4.3 7.9-.4.7-.8 1.3-1.2 1.9l-.6.9c-.5.8-.8 1.5-.8 2.1.1 1.3 1.5 2.3 2.1 2.7.5.3 1 .6 1.5.8 1.4.7 3 1.5 4.1 3.1.7.9 1 2.1 1 3.1-.1 2.2-1.7 3.8-4.7 4.7-.7.2-1.4.3-2 .5-.7.1-1.5-.4-1.6-1.1-.1-.7.4-1.5 1.1-1.6.6-.1 1.2-.2 1.7-.4 2.4-.7 2.7-1.5 2.7-2.2 0-.5-.1-.9-.5-1.4-.7-1-1.9-1.6-3.1-2.3-.6-.3-1.1-.6-1.7-.9-2.1-1.3-3.3-3-3.4-4.9-.1-1.2.3-2.4 1.2-3.8.2-.3.4-.7.7-1 .4-.5.7-1 1-1.5.8-1.6.7-3.6-.2-5.2-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.5-1.3-1.4-3.2-2.2-5.2-2.2-1.9 0-3.7.8-5 2.2-.2.2-.3.4-.4.5-.9 1.6-1 3.6-.2 5.2.3.5.6 1 1 1.5.2.3.5.6.7 1 .9 1.3 1.3 2.6 1.2 3.8-.1 1.9-1.3 3.6-3.4 4.9-.5.3-1.1.6-1.7.9C6.9 23.4 5.7 24 5 25c-.3.4-.5.9-.5 1.4 0 .7.4 1.5 2.7 2.2 2.4.7 4.9.7 7.6.7h.8c.4 0 .8.2 1 .5.3.3.4.7.3 1.1 0 .6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.1z"></path></svg></span></a>

                    <div class="NavigationPlayer__nav__1GtYE NavigationPlayer__navOpen__kmIqC">

                      <ul class="NavigationPlayer__navSub__SIRkf">

                        <li class="NavigationPlayer__signUp__2AOMK">

                          <a href="https://signin.rockstargames.com/create/?cid=socialclub&amp;lang=en-US&amp;returnUrl=%2F" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj NavigationPlayer__highlight__2lzxA" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

                        <li class="NavigationPlayer__signIn__3qaVH"><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>
                        <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="legal">Legal</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="privacy">Privacy</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="support">Support</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="cookies">Cookies</a></li>

                        <li><div class="NavigationPlayer__languageWrap__2jmcz">
                            <div class="UI__DropDown__custom-select LanguageSelector__dropdown__2uNdg">
                                <select class="select" data-ui-name="languageSelector">
                                    <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
                                    <option value="en-US">English</option>
                                    <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
                                    <option value="es-MX">Español Latinoamérica</option>
                                    <option value="fr-FR">Français</option>
                                    <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
                                    <option value="ja-JP">日本語</option>
                                    <option value="ko-KR">한국어</option>
                                    <option value="pl-PL">Polski</option>
                                    <option value="pt-BR">Português do Brasil</option>
                                    <option value="ru-RU">Русский</option>
                                    <option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option>
                                    <option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option>
                                </select>
                                <script>
                                  document.addEventListener("load", hideDropDownOnLoad());
                                  function hideDropDownOnLoad() {
                                  // Is called when the document loads to hide the dropdown
                                  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
                                  dropdown.style.display = "none";
                                  function showDropDown() {
                                  // Get the dropdown
                                  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
                                  // Check to see if the dropdown is currently hidden
                                  if(dropdown.style.display === "none") {
                                  // It is hidden so show the drop down
                                  dropdown.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                // The dropdown is visible so hide it
                                dropdown.style.display = "none";
                              }
                            }
                          </script>
```
````

```css
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__wrap__fQdBR {
    padding: 0 0.625rem;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__inner__1LxZ7 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1420px;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 88.75em) {
  .NavigationTop__inner__1LxZ7 {
    padding: 0 0.625rem;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3 {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 0.625rem;
  position: relative;
}

.NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3 .NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 32px;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
}

.NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW svg {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3:focus .NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW svg,
.NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3:hover .NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW svg {
  fill: url("#gradient") #f7931e;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.NavigationTop__hamburger__KU-ur {
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__hamburger__KU-ur {
    display: none;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__search__UDzfT {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.NavigationTop__groupLeft__3lTQW {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__groupLeft__3lTQW {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-width: 104px;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-width: 0;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__logo__3GmAs {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__logo__3GmAs {
    -ms-flex-order: -1;
    order: -1;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__logoThunder__1m1Ou {
  background-image: url(../images/react/logo/thunder.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  width: 34px;
}

@media (max-width: 64.6875em) {
  .pl-PL .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 68.125em) {
  .pt-BR .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 69.375em) {
  .es-ES .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy,
  .es-MX .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 70.625em) {
  .fr-FR .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy,
  .ru-RU .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
    display: none;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
  background-image: url(../images/react/logo/socialclub_small.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: none;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 128px;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__logo__3GmAs:hover .NavigationTop__logoSocialClub__1EfPy {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(252, 175, 23, 0.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(252, 175, 23, 0.5));
}

.NavigationTop__notifications__2lGKZ {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__notifications__2lGKZ {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__notifications__2lGKZ:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.NavigationTop__notifications__2lGKZ .NavigationTop__new__1FmP_ {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #bd0808;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  right: -5px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}

.NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li {
  position: relative;
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP::after,
.NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ::after {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f7931e, #fcaf17);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  content: ' ';
  display: none;
  height: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 88%;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP::after,
  .NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ::after {
    left: 6%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li:hover .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP::after,
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP:focus::after {
    display: block;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP.NavigationTop__navLinkActive__1-yPY {
  color: #f7931e;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP.NavigationTop__navLinkActive__1-yPY {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ.NavigationTop__navLinkActive__1-yPY {
  color: #fcaf17;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP.NavigationTop__navLinkActive__1-yPY::after {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f7931e, #fcaf17);
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK.NavigationTop__navSubOn__QIUAx,
  .NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48.NavigationTop__navSubOn__QIUAx {
    display: block;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK::before,
.NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48::before {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #999999);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #999999);
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
}

.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK::before {
  left: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK::before {
    left: 60px;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48::before {
  left: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48::before {
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    left: -6px;
    top: 22px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li:hover>.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK,
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li:hover>.NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48,
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li>.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK:focus,
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li>.NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48:focus {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem 1.25rem 1.875rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f7931e, #fcaf17);
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li ul li ul li .NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ {
  padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLinkToggle__2zB_R {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navLinkToggle__2zB_R {
    display: none;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK,
.NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48 {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  top: calc(100% + -1px);
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK,
  .NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSubSub__2Xm48 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__menuOpen__r1RJG {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .NavigationTop__menuOpen__r1RJG body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ>li:nth-child(even) .NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP {
    background-color: #fafafa;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navSub__3YEgK>li:nth-child(even) .NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__overlay__h6uED {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    transition: 0.1s 0.2s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 5000;
  }
  .NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ li:hover>.NavigationTop__overlay__h6uED {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP.NavigationTop__navLinkHighlight__2uEEp,
.NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ.NavigationTop__navLinkHighlight__2uEEp {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.NavigationTop__navLink__k_LuP.NavigationTop__navLinkHighlight__2uEEp::after,
.NavigationTop__navLinkSub__2QMkZ.NavigationTop__navLinkHighlight__2uEEp::after {
  color: #ff0000;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .NavigationTop__signUp__15T16,
  .NavigationTop__signIn__38Mfg {
    display: none;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__navSignedOut__2qibz {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 83.125em) {
  .NavigationTop__navSignedOut__2qibz {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}

.NavigationTop__avatar__2rxHG:hover::after {
  border: 2px solid #f7931e;
}

.NavigationTop__avatar__2rxHG {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 0.625rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.NavigationTop__avatar__2rxHG img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.NavigationTop__avatar__2rxHG::after {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  height: 36px;
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 36px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.NavigationTop__nav__1InFQ:hover .NavigationTop__avatar__2rxHG::after {
  border: 2px solid #f7931e;
}

.NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi">
  <span class="NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7">
                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <a onclick="myFunction()" href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3" data-ui-name="info">

                          <span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon">
                              <path d="M15.6 32s-.1 0 0 0h-.8c-2.7 0-5.6 0-8.4-.8-3-.9-4.6-2.4-4.7-4.7-.1-1.1.3-2.2 1-3.1 1.1-1.5 2.7-2.4 4.1-3.1.5-.3 1-.5 1.5-.8.6-.4 2-1.4 2.1-2.7 0-.6-.2-1.3-.8-2.1l-.6-.9c-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1.2-1.9-1.2-2.5-1-5.6.4-7.9.2-.3.4-.6.7-.9 1.8-2 4.3-3.1 7-3.1 2.7-.1 5.3 1.1 7.2 3 .3.3.6.7.8 1 1.4 2.3 1.5 5.4.3 7.9-.4.7-.8 1.3-1.2 1.9l-.6.9c-.5.8-.8 1.5-.8 2.1.1 1.3 1.5 2.3 2.1 2.7.5.3 1 .6 1.5.8 1.4.7 3 1.5 4.1 3.1.7.9 1 2.1 1 3.1-.1 2.2-1.7 3.8-4.7 4.7-.7.2-1.4.3-2 .5-.7.1-1.5-.4-1.6-1.1-.1-.7.4-1.5 1.1-1.6.6-.1 1.2-.2 1.7-.4 2.4-.7 2.7-1.5 2.7-2.2 0-.5-.1-.9-.5-1.4-.7-1-1.9-1.6-3.1-2.3-.6-.3-1.1-.6-1.7-.9-2.1-1.3-3.3-3-3.4-4.9-.1-1.2.3-2.4 1.2-3.8.2-.3.4-.7.7-1 .4-.5.7-1 1-1.5.8-1.6.7-3.6-.2-5.2-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.5-1.3-1.4-3.2-2.2-5.2-2.2-1.9 0-3.7.8-5 2.2-.2.2-.3.4-.4.5-.9 1.6-1 3.6-.2 5.2.3.5.6 1 1 1.5.2.3.5.6.7 1 .9 1.3 1.3 2.6 1.2 3.8-.1 1.9-1.3 3.6-3.4 4.9-.5.3-1.1.6-1.7.9C6.9 23.4 5.7 24 5 25c-.3.4-.5.9-.5 1.4 0 .7.4 1.5 2.7 2.2 2.4.7 4.9.7 7.6.7h.8c.4 0 .8.2 1 .5.3.3.4.7.3 1.1 0 .6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.1z"></path></svg></span></a>

  <div class="NavigationPlayer__nav__1GtYE NavigationPlayer__navOpen__kmIqC">

    <ul class="NavigationPlayer__navSub__SIRkf">

      <li class="NavigationPlayer__signUp__2AOMK">

        <a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj NavigationPlayer__highlight__2lzxA" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

      <li class="NavigationPlayer__signIn__3qaVH"><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="legal">Legal</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="privacy">Privacy</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="support">Support</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="cookies">Cookies</a></li>

      <li>
        <div class="NavigationPlayer__languageWrap__2jmcz">
          <div class="UI__DropDown__custom-select LanguageSelector__dropdown__2uNdg">
            <select class="select" data-ui-name="languageSelector">
              <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
              <option value="en-US">English</option>
              <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
              <option value="es-MX">Español Latinoamérica</option>
              <option value="fr-FR">Français</option>
              <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
              <option value="ja-JP">日本語</option>
              <option value="ko-KR">한국어</option>
              <option value="pl-PL">Polski</option>
              <option value="pt-BR">Português do Brasil</option>
              <option value="ru-RU">Русский</option>
              <option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option>
              <option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to work, so what I did is made an example. What you need to do is on document load set the style.display of your dropdown to none.

Then add the showDropDown function to an onclick method for your button, so that you can hide/show the button depending on its current state. It checks to see if the button is currently hidden, if it IS hidden it then shows the div, if not it hides the div.

```js
document.addEventListener("load", hideDropDownOnLoad());

function hideDropDownOnLoad() {
  // Is called when the document loads to hide the dropdown
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  dropdown.style.display = "none";
}

function showDropDown() {
  // Get the dropdown
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  
  // Check to see if the dropdown is currently hidden
  if(dropdown.style.display === "none") {
    // It is hidden so show the drop down
    dropdown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // The dropdown is visible so hide it
    dropdown.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" onclick="showDropDown()">Click for More...</a>
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li>Option 4</li>
      <li>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated your actual code for this to work, see below:

```js
document.addEventListener("load", hideDropDownOnLoad());

function hideDropDownOnLoad() {
  // Is called when the document loads to hide the dropdown
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  dropdown.style.display = "none";
}

function showDropDown() {
  // Get the dropdown
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  
  // Check to see if the dropdown is currently hidden
  if(dropdown.style.display === "none") {
    // It is hidden so show the drop down
    dropdown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // The dropdown is visible so hide it
    dropdown.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="NavigationTop__groupRight__3UIqi">
  <span class="NavigationTop__navPlayer__2TGn7">
                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <a onclick="showDropDown()" href="#" class="NavigationTop__icon__32Kg3" data-ui-name="info">

                          <span class="NavigationTop__iconBg__3nlrW">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="16" width="16" class="UI__Icon__icon">
                              <path d="M15.6 32s-.1 0 0 0h-.8c-2.7 0-5.6 0-8.4-.8-3-.9-4.6-2.4-4.7-4.7-.1-1.1.3-2.2 1-3.1 1.1-1.5 2.7-2.4 4.1-3.1.5-.3 1-.5 1.5-.8.6-.4 2-1.4 2.1-2.7 0-.6-.2-1.3-.8-2.1l-.6-.9c-.4-.6-.8-1.2-1.2-1.9-1.2-2.5-1-5.6.4-7.9.2-.3.4-.6.7-.9 1.8-2 4.3-3.1 7-3.1 2.7-.1 5.3 1.1 7.2 3 .3.3.6.7.8 1 1.4 2.3 1.5 5.4.3 7.9-.4.7-.8 1.3-1.2 1.9l-.6.9c-.5.8-.8 1.5-.8 2.1.1 1.3 1.5 2.3 2.1 2.7.5.3 1 .6 1.5.8 1.4.7 3 1.5 4.1 3.1.7.9 1 2.1 1 3.1-.1 2.2-1.7 3.8-4.7 4.7-.7.2-1.4.3-2 .5-.7.1-1.5-.4-1.6-1.1-.1-.7.4-1.5 1.1-1.6.6-.1 1.2-.2 1.7-.4 2.4-.7 2.7-1.5 2.7-2.2 0-.5-.1-.9-.5-1.4-.7-1-1.9-1.6-3.1-2.3-.6-.3-1.1-.6-1.7-.9-2.1-1.3-3.3-3-3.4-4.9-.1-1.2.3-2.4 1.2-3.8.2-.3.4-.7.7-1 .4-.5.7-1 1-1.5.8-1.6.7-3.6-.2-5.2-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.5-1.3-1.4-3.2-2.2-5.2-2.2-1.9 0-3.7.8-5 2.2-.2.2-.3.4-.4.5-.9 1.6-1 3.6-.2 5.2.3.5.6 1 1 1.5.2.3.5.6.7 1 .9 1.3 1.3 2.6 1.2 3.8-.1 1.9-1.3 3.6-3.4 4.9-.5.3-1.1.6-1.7.9C6.9 23.4 5.7 24 5 25c-.3.4-.5.9-.5 1.4 0 .7.4 1.5 2.7 2.2 2.4.7 4.9.7 7.6.7h.8c.4 0 .8.2 1 .5.3.3.4.7.3 1.1 0 .6-.6 1.1-1.3 1.1z"></path></svg></span></a>

  <div id="dropdown" class="NavigationPlayer__nav__1GtYE NavigationPlayer__navOpen__kmIqC">

    <ul class="NavigationPlayer__navSub__SIRkf">

      <li class="NavigationPlayer__signUp__2AOMK">

        <a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj NavigationPlayer__highlight__2lzxA" data-ui-name="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>

      <li class="NavigationPlayer__signIn__3qaVH"><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="signIn">Sign In</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="legal">Legal</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="privacy">Privacy</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="support">Support</a></li>

      <li><a href="#" class="NavigationPlayer__navLink__2oeuj" data-ui-name="cookies">Cookies</a></li>

      <li>
        <div class="NavigationPlayer__languageWrap__2jmcz">
          <div class="UI__DropDown__custom-select LanguageSelector__dropdown__2uNdg">
            <select class="select" data-ui-name="languageSelector">
              <option value="de-DE">Deutsch</option>
              <option value="en-US">English</option>
              <option value="es-ES">Español</option>
              <option value="es-MX">Español Latinoamérica</option>
              <option value="fr-FR">Français</option>
              <option value="it-IT">Italiano</option>
              <option value="ja-JP">日本語</option>
              <option value="ko-KR">한국어</option>
              <option value="pl-PL">Polski</option>
              <option value="pt-BR">Português do Brasil</option>
              <option value="ru-RU">Русский</option>
              <option value="zh-TW">繁體中文</option>
              <option value="zh-CN">简体中文</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: it has not worked have i done it correctly (I have updated code above)

Comment: @BenT144 I checked your code and it doesn't look like it was updated. I update my answer with your specific code, all I did was add in the JS functions from my original answer, added `id="dropdown"` to your dropdown, and the onclick to your button like I said.

Comment: Thank you so much this is much appreciated